# Deleted constructor - MSVC reports an error, Clang doesn't

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```
class SILPassPipelinePlan final {
public:
  SILPassPipelinePlan() = default;
  ~SILPassPipelinePlan() = default;
  SILPassPipelinePlan(const SILPassPipelinePlan &) = default;
  SILPassPipelinePlan(SILPassPipelinePlan &&) = delete;

  SILPassPipelinePlan x() {
    SILPassPipelinePlan P;

    return P;
  }
};

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

MSVC reports the following error:

> 1>consoleapplication2.cpp(13): error C2280: 'SILPassPipelinePlan::SILPassPipelinePlan(SILPassPipelinePlan &&)': attempting to reference a deleted function
>
> 1>consoleapplication2.cpp(8): note: see declaration of 'SILPassPipelinePlan::SILPassPipelinePlan'

Clang and GCC don't.

From a specification point of view, which compiler is correct? Is this an MSVC bug, or a Clang bug?

MSVC is from the latest Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, Clang is version 3.9.0.

Comment: Which `-std` flag are you passing to Clang and GCC? Move constructor deletion has undergone important changes between C++11 and C++14.

Comment: @Angew no specific flags. Try it out here: http://rextester.com/WJMW74714

Comment: Based on that rextester link, you're using `-std=c++14`. You should add this info to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++11 introduced implicit moves in certain scenarios—[yours included](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#3):

> In the following copy-initialization contexts, a move operation might
>   be used instead of a copy operation:
>
> - If the expression in a return statement ([stmt.return]) is a (possibly parenthesized) *id-expression* that names an object with
>     automatic storage duration declared in the body or
>     *parameter-declaration-clause* of the innermost enclosing function or *lambda-expression*, or
> - […]
>
> overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first
>   performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue. If the first
>   overload resolution fails, […]

Clang (the only accepting implementation, btw.) either misinterprets "fails" to include the selection of deleted functions, or applies [[over.match.funcs]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#8) too laxly. See bug [31025](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=31025).

Comment: Thanks. Something like `return const_cast<const SILPassPipelinePlan&>(P);` fixes the error - but does this have side effects?

Comment: @HBellamy For one, it prevents copy elision from being applied. Is there any specific reason you *delete* the move ctor instead of simply not providing it? You realize that not providing one yourself means that in your case, none will be implicitly declared? See [\[class.copy.ctor\]/(8.1)](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#8.1).

Answer (score 4):

All versions of GCC on Wandbox reject this code. Are you by any chance testing this on a Mac and using its Clang-masquerading-as-GCC?

This has nothing to do with P0135. Clang is simply taking an excessively liberal reading of "fails" in what is currently [[class.copy.elision]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.copy.elision#3), which says that in this situation

> overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first
>   performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue. If the first
>   overload resolution **fails** or was not performed, [...], overload
>   resolution is performed again, considering the object as an lvalue.

That overload resolution doesn't fail; it succeeds and selects the move constructor, which happens to be deleted. That should be the end of the matter.

This has been reported as [bug 31025](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=31025).

Comment: @columbo any response?

Comment: @HBellamy Say what? I amended my answer accordingly.